# dynamically change uitabbar items

Tags: iphone

I am working on app where i need to display a tab bar controller with different viewscontrollers. I mean when i go from one page to other the the items in tab bar should change and when i go back to previous page the items should again become same as they were earlier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it. I just reloaded the tabbar with view controllers and it is working fine.